# Flag and Text field - or just one field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where a user may need an Interpreter, and if so, the language required. If the user sets the checkbox to true, they're forced to TYPE in the language, which can be stored in a field.

Would the recommended idea be to store both the checkbox (`InterpreterRequired BIT NOT NULL`) and a `VARCHAR` for the actual language, OR would it be suitable to just store the language, and let the UI decide to show true or false based on an empty language field?

I prefer two fields, but people are giving me funning looks, thinking one field is enough.

Note, language is free text. They don't want a selection (ID).

Comment: There isn't a right or wrong answer here. There are valid points on either side of this one. I have to say that a textbox for language is asking for problems. Why not a dropdown?

Comment: Of course one field is enough, it depends on how you want to handle the case. I'm mostly a database layer developer, so I'd probably go for both columns, since it clarifies the intention a bit more. This is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: You have stated this is a matter of opinion, just like Sean agrees. The flag is redundant and I dont see a reason to have it, unless reporting and query performance is required where the flag may help to get quicker results, and even then one may challenge the gains.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange - With regards the dropdown - I have begged them to do this, but the client has demanded freetext. :( We had the same with religion - which was freetext, and they later changed their mind. I'm hoping history will repeat it's self. :)

Comment: As others have stated, easiest would most certainly be to use a single varchar column. This column could either be NULL when no interpreter needed or it could be set to default to a language of your choosing.